# Comparing large numbers of values using php arrays

Tags: php, arrays, largenumber

I have to compare two very large number of values, for that I put them in arrays but it didn't work. Below is the code I use. Is this the most efficient way? I have set the time and memory to unlimited as well. `error 101 (connection reset) unknown error` this is error shown by chrome

```
for ($k = 0; $k < sizeof($pid); $k++) {
    $out = 0;
    for ($m = 0; $m < sizeof($oid); $m++) {
        if ($pid[$k] == $oid[$m]) // $pid have 300000 indexes
        //and $oid have about 500000 indexes               
        {
            $out++;
        }

    }
    if ($out) {
        echo "OID for ID ".$pid[$k]." = ".$out;
        echo "<br>";
    } 
}
```

Comment: connection reset after how much time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't work how?  Won't give you an answer? 
You're comparing every possible pair.  How many combinations is that?  More than 10^13.  That will take something like an hour on a modern machine, if you don't run out of memory first.
A more efficient way would be to sort them first: NlogN + MlogM + N + M time, instead of N*M time.
Sorting a list of size x with a comparison sort takes [x*log(x) time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm).  Then, you can walk from the front of each list once, confident that if there are any matches you will find them.  This takes linear time.

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @ bdares
i hv set the time and memory to max, no issue of time, but it stops and browser says cant show the page.

Comment: @ bdares
 NlogN + MlogM + N + M time, instead of N*M time.
wht does this mean? i dint get.

Comment: error 101 (connection reset) unknown error this is error shown by chrome